# Kotlin flow and collect synchroniously

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have such code and i want to collect results of api call  inside coroutine and then join this job and return it from function

```
 private suspend fun loadRangeInternal(offset: Int, limit: Int):  List<Activity> {

        // load data from Room database
        // calling Retrofit request
        // and caching them if there is no data available

        var activities: List<Activity> = listOf()

        val job = GlobalScope.launch {
            repo.loadActivitiesOf(settings.companyId, offset, limit)
                .collect {
                    networkError.send(it.error)

                    when (it.status) {
                        Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                            activities = it.data ?: listOf()
                            isLoading.send(false)
                        }
                        Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                            isLoading.send(true)
                        }
                        Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                            isLoading.send(false)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        job.join()

        Timber.d("Activities loaded: $activities")

        return activities
    }
```

I've also tried async instead of launch, and await instead of join

Comment: I'm not sure I understand a reason to have he whole `GlobaleScope.launch { ... }` and `job.join()` in the first place. It looks that if you remove them and just call `.collect { ... }`  it'll work just as you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

it's generally recommended to avoid using GlobalScope for launching coroutines and instead use a coroutine scope tied to the lifecycle of the component, such as a ViewModel or an Activity/Fragment.

Try below code:

```
private suspend fun loadRangeInternal(offset: Int, limit: Int): List<Activity> {

    var activities: List<Activity> = listOf()

    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repo.loadActivitiesOf(settings.companyId, offset, limit)
            .collect {
                networkError.send(it.error)

                when (it.status) {
                    Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                        activities = it.data ?: listOf()
                        isLoading.send(false)
                    }
                    Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                        isLoading.send(true)
                    }
                    Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                        isLoading.send(false)
                    }
                }
            }

        activities
    }

    Timber.d("Activities loaded: $result")

    return result
}
```

Comment: it looks like hack or code for testing purposed not production ready?

Comment: Yea looks hack (ish) solution to me as well.

Comment: I changed to using callbacks but  and call this callback from .collect { } but I think coroutines are used to not need callbacks

Comment: Yes, you are right it's a hack. I also didn't find much useful so I used like that for testing one of my function